# RewriteRule override Redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'd like to put two rules in my .htaccess.
First priority, manual redirections.
Then, every others URLs are redirect to another domain.

My .htaccess works when I use only the "redirect" or when I use only the "rewriterule", but when I use both,  the rewriteRule override "redirect" and I can't choose to redirect some URLs manually. 
However the redirect line is higher in the code so I think it should be the priority.

My .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /directory/redirectiontest/pagebase1.php http://v2.mywebsite.com/nous-contacter.html
Redirect 301 /directory/redirectiontest/pagebase2.php http://v2.mywebsite.com/nous-contacter.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://v2.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for help :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` is overriding your `Redirects` because you have mixed `Redirect` with `RewriteRule` . Theses directives are part of two different Apache modules and  have different runtime behaviour. Use `RewriteRule`  for your manual url redirection.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^/?directory/redirectiontest/pagebase1.php http://v2.mywebsite.com/nous-contacter.html [L,R]
 RewriteRule ^/?directory/redirectiontest/pagebase2.php http://v2.mywebsite.com/nous-contacter.html [L,R]


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://v2.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about those mysterious "different runtime behaviours"? Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha There is nothing mysterious :) . By `Diffrent runtime` I meant to say that these two directives run differently "not in order"  on server. (RewriteRule first) as mod-rewrite takes precedence over mod-alias.

Comment: Ah, so you mean at runtime the modules are treated different (in a specific order, one after another), not that the modules behave different at runtime, depending on whatever. I got that wrong from your description. Thanks!